# Book where aliens implant a human brain in a fighting machine

Tags: story-identification, books, alien-abduction

I'm looking for the title of a book about a human who is abducted by aliens and his brain is transplanted in an alien fighting machine or tank.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember _why_ the aliens did this?  You should check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for writing a good story-id question.

Comment: On a similar note, I was wondering whom the human-brain-in-a-tank was fighting. Other aliens? Humans? Something else? Do you remember if he ever got his brain transplanted back into a more normal body?

Comment: In [*The End of All Things*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_End_of_All_Things_(book)) (2015) by John Scalzi, aliens abduct a man and transplant his brain into a spaceship (rather than into a planetbound armored vehicle).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Novel from the 80s: Brain harvested and forced to fight in a war](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/189308/novel-from-the-80s-brain-harvested-and-forced-to-fight-in-a-war)

Comment: Apocalypse Troll by David Weber has something similar, one of the major characters is of a group that are cyborgs with brain transplants made from captured humans.  Most of that part is history, though, all offscreen, and the character is the enemy of the novel.

Comment: Answer isn't accepted yet, so we can't confirm it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Gaultheria Notice how "planetbound" takes on a whole new meaning when you put it near "spaceship".

Comment: @Spencer — Hmm, I see what you mean: "heading toward a planet". I should've said "groundside".

Comment: Was it an alien, or a robot? Do to you know how recent of a book it is?

Answer (score 12):

Most likely *A Plague of Demons* by Keith Laumer.  The protagonist's brain is harvested by doglike alien "demons".  It, along with other brains taken from dying soldiers on battlefields across the centuries, are enslaved and implanted in massive alien tanks and forced to fight in wars on distant planets.

This blurb taken from Goodreads talks about the first half of the book, before the Giant Alien War Machine part of the plot:

> When John Bravais was sent on a secret mission to observe a war in North Africa he found out more than it was safe for him to know - even after he had secretly been surgically transformed so that he was as strong as a Bolo tank, and nearly as tough: Wolf-like aliens, invisible to the ordinary eye, were harvesting the brains of the fallen fighters! Brevais might have become the Ultimate Warrior, but still he was only one man against A Plague of Demons.

Apparently, it's [available](http://baencd.freedoors.org/Books/A%20Plague%20of%20Demons/0743435885.htm) to read on the Baen Books site.

Comment: If this is correct, it would be a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/189308/novel-from-the-80s-brain-harvested-and-forced-to-fight-in-a-war

Comment: @DavidW, it probably is a dupe. But it's a dupe about a great read ;-)